# Extracting local HOG features after applying to an image in Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, scikit-image

I am using skimage learn in python to extract HOG features from an image.

skimage.features.hog returns a tuple (fd,hog_arr) where fd stands for HOG feature descriptors and 'hog_arr' is for visual representation of HOG features. (This is what I understood after looking at http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_hog.html)

I want to apply HOG on the entire image and extract the specific local HOG features out of it. For example, if the image is a face, I want to apply HOG on face and extract the hog features corresponding to 'eye' of the facial image.

As fd variable stores the actual HOG features of the image, I am not understanding how to extract such specific HOG features corresponding to a specific location inside the image ( I am able to visualize the HOG features corresponding to the image through 'hog_arr' through cv2.imshow)

How to go about this? Any help?

Comment: Check out [this archive](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/tag/histogram-of-oriented-gradients/) to see if you get anything useful.

Comment: @Jeru but the archive that you shared is about using HOG from opencv. I am using HOG from skimage